# Are there any projects of flying launch pads on high altitude ballons?

Tags: launch, design-alternative, future-missions, balloons

It is possible to fly up to 30 km with [high altitude balloons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_balloon). Is it possible to build an [island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laputa) there with launch pad on it? Will it help to fly to space?

Comment: not quite an island, but [SpaceRyde](https://www.spaceryde.com/) thinks it will help!

Comment: That was a quick close. If you you think your question is sufficiently different from the duplicate and not answered there, you can edit the question, include a link to that one and explain what things are not answered there, and then it can be considered for reopening.